# How to get a label's gender for non-english languages in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I was wondering how we can get the gender of Wikidata results. For example

```
SELECT ?s ?sLabel 
WHERE
{
  ?s wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ; rdfs:label ?sLabel .
   FILTER (lang(?sLabel) = 'fr') .
  } limit 10
```

I want to get not only the labels in French but also their gender, like this

```
Canada        Masculin
Bangladesh    Masculin
Norvège       Feminin
```

Is there anyway to do this using Wikidata queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ?country_label ?language_code ?gender_label {
  ?s wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
     rdfs:label ?country_label .
  FILTER (lang(?country_label) = ?language_code)
  ?lexeme ontolex:sense?/wdt:P5137 ?s ;
          dct:language/wdt:P424 ?language_code .
  OPTIONAL { 
     ?lexeme wdt:P5185 ?gender .
     ?gender rdfs:label ?gender_label .
     FILTER (lang(?gender_label) = ?language_code)
  }
} VALUES (?language_code) {('de')}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry_label%20%3Flanguage_code%20%3Fgender_label%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256%20%3B%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_label%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry_label%29%20%3D%20%3Flanguage_code%29%0A%20%20%3Flexeme%20ontolex%3Asense%3F%2Fwdt%3AP5137%20%3Fs%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Alanguage%2Fwdt%3AP424%20%3Flanguage_code%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Flexeme%20wdt%3AP5185%20%3Fgender%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fgender%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fgender_label%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fgender_label%29%20%3D%20%3Flanguage_code%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20VALUES%20%28%3Flanguage_code%29%20%7B%28%27de%27%29%7D%0A)

More info: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Lexicographical_data